# exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0) on drawer items

Tags: ios, swift3

I have been getting this error of exc_bad_behavior. have been gone through all the possible answers here but unfortunately none of them helped. If anyone can please help me with this, it would be more than thankful

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    switch (indexPath.section,indexPath.row)
    {
    case (0,0) :

        let currentOrderViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CurrentOrdersViewController") as! CurrentOrdersViewController

                    let currentOrdersNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: currentOrderViewController)

                    let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

                    appDelegate.centerContainer!.centerViewController = currentOrdersNavController //exc_bad_behavior error pops here at runtime
                    appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggle(MMDrawerSide.left, animated: true, completion: nil)

                    break;

    case (0,1) :
        let orderHistoryController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OrderHistoryViewController") as! OrderHistoryViewController

        let orderHistoryNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: orderHistoryController)

        let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

        appDelegate.centerContainer?.centerViewController = orderHistoryNavController //if replaced with "?" nothing is displayed
        appDelegate.centerContainer?.toggle(MMDrawerSide.left, animated: true, completion: nil)

        break;
```

**login function where all the code actually works**

```
 @IBAction func btnLogin(_ sender: Any) {


    var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

            var rootViewController = appDelegate.window!.rootViewController

            let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

            //let mainInitial = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SplashController") as! SplashController

            let centerViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CenterViewController") as! CenterViewController

            let leftViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SideMenuViewController") as! SideMenuViewController


            //let mainView = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainInitial)
            let leftSideNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: leftViewController)
            let centerNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)

            let centerContainer:MMDrawerController = MMDrawerController(center: centerNav, leftDrawerViewController: leftSideNav)//centerContainer used here



            centerContainer.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureMode.panningCenterView
            centerContainer.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureMode.panningCenterView

            appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = centerContainer
            appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


}
```

Comment: Before the line at which the crash occurs please print appDelegate.centerContainer value , please tell what it shows

Comment: The error code shows that the debugger wasn't able to catch the actual error. Please set up an exception breakpoint in debugger and include the actual error in the question.

Comment: it says "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb) " @user1000

Comment: Where are you assigning this centerContainer a value in your code?

Comment: its assigned in AppDelegate as "var centerContainer: MMDrawerController?" and also in the same function where it has been used @user1000

Comment: That's a declaration, not an assignment.  Where do you actually set it equal to something?

Comment: i have also added 1 more function where centerContainer is being used. Please check and let me know where my code is not working. @Phillip Mills

Comment: In your working sample, `centerContainer` is a local variable.  If you use the same name as an instance variable, then you need to change `let centerContainer:MMDrawerController =` to just `centerContainer =`.

Comment: thanx a lot @PhillipMills